# I am stuck in "If" & "Else" function one of my android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, if-statement, textview

I my app I am fetch some text data from the server and showing this text data in the TextView. Here is something works fine. I am add an little arrow ImageView right to the TextView and this TextView is expandable so when TextView is more then 2 lines and if anyone click this TextView it expand and again click to shrink and I am also add an little arrow image right to the TextView (so user understant that it is an expandable text), here is everything is fine all code are works perfectly but now I want to remove this litter arrow image when the TextView is under 2 lines and when TextView is more then 2 lines it show. I want to tell you one more thing that I am also add a rotation in the arrow image so when the user click the text the little arrow image rotate the 180 degree and also text is expand and when user click the text second time arrow image again rotate to his previous position and text is shrink in 2 lines.

I want to remove this little arrow when the text is under 2 lies I do not want to remove the arrow image when text line more then 2, I'm guessing you understand.

I am new to the Java Code and I am learning is language so now I want to learn how to do this implementation in my app, I have add my code below so that you can understand batter.

```
textViewMyVideoTitle.setText(videoLists.get(0).getVideo_title());
my_title_layout_expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    if (isTextViewClicked) {
      //This will shrink textview to 2 lines if it is expanded.
      textViewMyVideoTitle.setText(videoLists.get(0).getVideo_title());
      myTitleImageView.setRotation(imageView.getRotation() + 0);
      myTitleImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      textViewMyVideoTitle.setMaxLines(2);
      isTextViewClicked = false;
    } else {
      //This will expand the textview if it is of 2 lines
      textViewMyVideoTitle.setText(videoLists.get(0).getVideo_title());
      myTitleImageView.setRotation(imageView.getRotation() - 180);
      myTitleImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      textViewMyVideoTitle.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
      isTextViewClicked = true;
    }
  }
});
```

**So anybody can help me to achieve this code**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you say, your text doesnt have more than 2 lines, so your function wont work until the text has more than 2 lines.

Comment: No, some of the video have more then 2 lines.

Comment: I want to remove this little arrow image when textview have only two lines

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use TextView's `getLineCount()` method to get this info and decide.
So I mean outside your `onClickListener` do something like this:

```
if (textViewMyVideoTitle.getLineCount() <= 2) {
        my_title_layout_expand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        my_title_layout_expand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Or since it gives you the right number only after layout been 'rendered' you might need the following:

```
textViewMyVideoTitle.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    // Get the line count and put the if-else statement here
}});
```

Comment: The way you have described it is working on OnClickListener, but when I put it outside the OnClickListener, it does not work.

Comment: I saw the second code ```textViewMyVideoTitle.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    // Get the line count and put the if-else statement here
}});``` which you had given, but that too did not work.

Comment: Does the `getLineCount()` return 0 ?

I also think I used the wrong widget's name for setting visibility in my example (it should be `myTitleImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` probably. However assume you wrote it correclty in your code